# Change Matplotlib font without impacting global

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, settings

I have a function that creates a plot, displays it, and saves it:

```
def make_a_plot():
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()
    plt.safefig('./my_plot.png')
```

I want to the plot to be un-impacted by any settings currently in place without making global changes that impact the settings they are using:

```
# User can set whatever plotting settings they want
plt.style.use('ggplot') 

def make_a_plot():

    #clear settings and modify font family
    rcdefaults()
    rcParams['font.family'] = 'sans-serif'

    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()
    plt.safefig('./my_plot.png')

# Use the function
make_a_plot(x,y)

# Create a second plot with their ORIGINAL settings
plt.plot(x2,y2)
plt.show()
```

How can I ensure that the plot created by the function is **not** impacted by the user's settings and that plots created after the function are not impacted by the use of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is somewhat unclear on the scope.

Is it the font properties (only) that you want to control / override regardless of the global settings or are do you want ignore ALL existing settings.

If you want to control font properties only you could use `fontproperties` parameter:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm

# Plt with customized font settings
def make_plot(ax, x, y):
    # Set the font dictionaries (for plot title and axis titles)
    title_font = {'fontname':'Arial', 'size':'16', 'color':'blue', 'weight':'normal'}   # This can be a long dictionary

    # Set the font properties for other places
    font_path = 'C:\Windows\Fonts\comic.ttf'
    font = fm.FontProperties(fname=font_path, size=14)
    axis_font = fm.FontProperties(fname=font_path, size=13)

    # Set the tick labels font
    for label in (ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels()):
        # label.set_fontname('Arial')
        # label.set_fontsize(13)
        label.set_font_properties(font)

    ax.plot(x, y, 'r-', label=u'Thin Red Line')
    ax.set_xlabel(u"X axis", fontproperties=axis_font)
    ax.set_ylabel(u"Y axis", fontproperties=axis_font)
    ax.set_title(u"This is the Title", **title_font)
    ax.legend(loc='lower right', prop=font, numpoints=1)
    ax.text(0.1, 5, u"Some text", fontproperties=font)

# A regular plot with global fong settings:
def regular_plot(ax, x, y):
    ax.plot(x,y, 'b-', label=u'Blue Line')
    ax.set_xlabel(u"X axis")
    ax.set_ylabel(u"Y axis")
    ax.set_title(u"This is the Title", axes=ax1)
    ax.legend(loc='lower right', numpoints=1)

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize=(9,3))
x = y = range(0, 10) # Some data

# 1st make a regular plot:
regular_plot(ax1, x, y)
# then make customized plot:
make_plot(ax2, x, y)
# then agains a regular plot:
regular_plot(ax3, x, y)
plt.show()
```

As you can see from the resulting graph customized plot did not change and was not affected by the global font setting.

[image]

If you are looking for a more complete control you might want to look at how to use [style sheets](http://matplotlib.org/users/style_sheets.html#style-sheets)

Comment: This is really helpful!  I just used fonts as an example and I want to make sure no other settings impact the way the graph looks.  I am going to accept it (especially since you included the style sheets link) but if somebody posts an example with full control (possibly using style sheets) I will switch to that answer.

Comment: Also, this function will be run by users in many different environments, is there a way to do it without the font_path reference?

Comment: `font_path` is just an example of how strict you can be. If you don't need it just use the example for `title_font` where you only give `fontname`. This, of course, assumes that OS (or matplotlib) is aware of this font name.